# How to send an email only to the last Google form submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using a Google Form for a classroom 'store' for students to purchase items from. A student cashier will fill out the form and then the sheet will send an email receipt to the student that purchased the items. The email sends fine with my current code and trigger, however, it sends an email to all submissions on each new submission. I only want it to send to the last submission. I know there's probably an easy fix to this and I'm just overlooking something. Here is my current code:

```
function sendAutomatedEmails() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = spreadSheet.getDataRange();
  
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i< data.length; i++) {
    (function(val) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[3];
      var message = 'At '+ row[0] + 'You purchased the following:' + '\n\n' + row[4] + '\n' + row[5] + '\n' + row[6] + '\n' + row[7] + '\n' + row[8] + '\n' + row[9] + '\n' + 'Your total cost is $' + row[10];
      var subject = 'Personal Purchase Reciept';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    })(i);
  }
}
```

I can't delete submissions every time as another classroom job is to check that purchases were paid for in our online bank system each week which is when the submissions will be deleted. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function sends the email for the data in the form submission even if multiple form submission come at the same time.  If you expect multiple submission at the same time you should consider using Lock Service in the function.  This does not have to do any additional reads of the data sheet because all of that info is already in the formSubmit event object.

```
function sendAutomatedEmails(e) {
  let message = 'At ' + e.values[0] + 'You purchased the following:' + '\n\n' + e.values[4] + '\n' + e.values[5]+ '\n' + e.values[6] + '\n' + e.values[7] + '\n' + e.values[8] + '\n' + e.values[9] + '\n' + 'Your total cost is $' + e.values[10];
  MailApp.sendEmail(e.values[3], 'Personal Purchase Receipt', message);
}

function runThisToSetupTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'sendAutomatedEmails').length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('SendAutomatedEmails').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would fit your need.. With .getDataRange() you get the hole sheet. Then you loop trough the data and sending an email for each row. I assume you got the script from somewhere?

```
function sendAutomatedEmails() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = spreadSheet.getRange(spreadSheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, spreadSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var row = dataRange[0];
  var emailAddress = row[3];
  var message = 'At ' + row[0] + 'You purchased the following:' + '\n\n' + row[4] + '\n' + row[5] + '\n' + row[6] + '\n' + row[7] + '\n' + row[8] + '\n' + row[9] + '\n' + 'Your total cost is $' + row[10];
  var subject = 'Personal Purchase Reciept';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: The code came from something I had done last year for some of us teachers that had at-home virtual learners. We were required to email their parents (elementary students) every day to check-in for attendance. That sheet wasn't tied to a Google form, it was just us filling in each row for a separate student and then changing the body text column each day, so it needed to email every line every time it ran. I knew I was overlooking something simple, but after spending the morning grading papers and other tasks I was just trying to get this done to enjoy the weekend.