# Send email to the new google form submission only

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm new to the Google apps script. I wrote a script to send emails when there is a new submission from google forms using data and template from a spreadsheet. However, it sends an email to not just the new submission but also to all of the previous submissions. The whole script is quite long, so I only copy a short part of it. Is there any way to fix it?

Here is the link to the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fhuwEndIS3khg3W19jpQnBAaCp_MMrD_bfATrdf2-4I/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you.

```
function sendEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calculation");
var lr = ss.getLastRow();
for (var i = 3; i<=lr;i++){

var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
var currentScore1 = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();


 MailApp.sendEmail(
currentEmail,
subjectline,
"HTML",
{ htmlBody: messageBody }
);

}
}
```

Comment: messageBody is undefined.  Why do you loop through  lines of a spreadsheet when all of the information in the current submission is in the event object of the onFormSubmit trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading the values from the spreadsheet take advantage of the form submit event object. This event object has two properties including the form submission values, one is an Array of form submission values in the same order than the sheet columns, the other is an object having a property for each question each of them having an Array of values. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

This shows the changes that need to done to your script:

```
function sendEmail(e) {

  var currentEmail = e.values[0];
  var currentName = e.values[2];
  var currentScore1 = e.values[3];


  MailApp.sendEmail(
   currentEmail,
   subjectline,
   "HTML",
   { htmlBody: messageBody }
  );

}
```

Note: In order to make the event object work, the function should be called by a Google Sheets form submit trigger.

Related

- [Event values and offset in Google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26492981/1595451)
- [How to send an email only to the last Google form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69065508/1595451)

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to look at the full version of my script? The entire script is quite more complicated than the one I copy here as I get value from different sheets. I'm not familiar with programming, so I would appreciate it if someone could look at my work and help identify the problem.

Comment: Hi @JoanaNguyen. I might do that through https://www.codementor.io/@rbn   tomorrow (I'm on GMT-05:00). And alternative is that you post a new question, providing more details about your use case.

Comment: Hi! I already posted the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73017272/how-to-only-send-email-to-the-last-google-form-submission. It includes the entire script and the spreadsheet as well. I would really appreciate it if you can give me some comments. Thanks